# Не работает скрипт python в игре

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, pyautogui, ctypes

Пишу бота. Есть некое окно игры, куда не проходят клики из Python. Пробовал и ctypes, и autopy и pyautogui и pydirectinput. Не хочет и всё, вне окна игры работает замечательно. Мало того, что он в самой игре не может ничего кликнуть, так даже и окно с игрой свернуть таким способом не получается.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? И как победить эту заразу?

```
# Пример с использованием ctypes
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) # left down
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) # left up

# Пример с использованием autopy
import autopy
autopy.mouse.click()

# Пример с использованием pyautogui
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click()

# Пример с использованием pydirectinput
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
pydirectinput.click()
```

p.s: игра в которой такая проблема: cristalix

Уже мучаюсь с этим 4 дня...

Comment: От администратора пробовали запускать?. Вообще когда игра перехватывает указатель мыши, она использует собственные координаты. Попробуйте покапать в этом направлении.

Comment: @YanWolf спасибо большое что подсказали! Ошибка была прям перед носом нужно было запустить файл с правами администратора а то я уже и не знал что делать